# Azure DevOps Server 2020 - How to edit the Description and Tags for a classic release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops-server-2020

In Azure DevOps Server 2020, when viewing a "classic" release pipeline (under *MyCollectionName* / *MyProjectName* / Pipelines / Release) there are column options to display a Description and Tags on the page. Also an option to filter the list of release by Tags.

I can see that you can specify a description at the time of creating a release but seemingly no way to edit it later? Also I cannot see any way to add tags to release so that they appear on this page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Update:
I either overlooked it or it was added later, but now tags on a classic release can be edited. To do it click on the link of the release, so the release view with status of the stages is opened. The click on the "Release" shape where type of the trigger and artifacts of the release are listed - a dialog window will be shown where it is possible to edit description and tags of the release.

Original answer:
I was also looking for it. I didn't found a way to do it in the new UI AKA Release (pipeline view). However I have found it's possible using the old UI AKA Release (old view).
To do it click on release name go open detailed view, then next to Edit command in the top line menu click on the .../More commands and select Release (old view).
In this view there are sections Details, where you can add/edit descriptions, and Tags, where you can add a new tag or remove an existing one.
I'm not sure if the functionality is absent on the new UI because Description and Tags are deprecated or it's just missed by a mistake.